# Почему нет ошибки одновременного доступа?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

я так понимаю разные потоки меняют одну и ту же переменную, и должен быть Exception

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  Int64 i = 0;
  Int64 j = 1;

  private void Test()
  {
    while (true)
    {
      j = -j;
      i += j;
    }
  }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    for (int n = 0; n < 4; ++n)
    {
      Thread t = new Thread(() => Test());
      t.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal;
      t.Start();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Возможны арифметические ошибки и/или некорректное поведение. Почему вы считаете, что должен быть Exception ?

Comment: @Kromster ну як же, записываем в одну область памяти с разных потоков...

Comment: Ничто не мешает потокам записывать одну и ту же область памяти. А чтобы помешать, надо делать блокировки. И то каждый поток должен соблюдать правила блокировки, потому что ничего не мешает ему наплювать на эти блокировки.

Comment: @Sergey т.е. Вы хотите сказать, что кроме арифметических ошибок более ничего я не получу?

Comment: И арифметических тоже скорей всего не будет. Если конечно не считать арифметической ошибкой неверный результат по причине неверного алгоритма.

Comment: @Sergey ну я ж как-то получаю в i значения -400, 800... и т.д.

Comment: Если получено -400, что это значит? Неправильно сложено 800 единиц или всё таки правильно сложено 400 "минус-единиц"? Это не ошибка арифметики. Это ошибка логики, алгоритма, который надеется на чёткую очерёдность арифметических операций, а на самом деле они выполняются в непредсказуемом порядке. Я вот понимаю деление на 0 - арифметическая ошибка. Ну там у Вас переполнение может быть возможно - тоже можно списать на ошибку арифметики.

Comment: похоже вы путаете потоки с процессами. При попытке доступа к памяти другого процесса действительно должно возникнуть исключение, MemoryAccessViolation кажется, но только если такой доступ не санкционирован ОС. Потоки же, относятся к одному процессу и совместно используют память процесса.

Comment: @rdorn Всё ясно, спасибо за разъяснение. У меня программа иногда валилась просто при использовании тессиляции и хиттеста в OGL, думал, что проблема как раз в межпоточном программировании (GPU-CPU), однако воспроизвести эту ошибку ручками не смог. В связи с чем у меня и возник данный вопрос. Значит будем копать в другом направлении...

Comment: тогда перенесу комментарий в ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже вы путаете потоки с процессами. При попытке доступа к памяти другого процесса действительно должно возникнуть исключение, но только если такой доступ не санкционирован ОС. Потоки же, относятся к одному процессу и совместно используют память процесса, поэтому в вашем коде ни каких исключений быть не должно.